# Display images tightly with html

Tags: html, css, image

How can I display images like this page?http://www.yunspace.com.cn/event/
no matter the height of the images, images fit tight with each other

Thanks!

Comment: yes it is possible you can make fiddle where i implement this

Comment: have you already tried with some codes? show us pls

Comment: I display images on this page:http://www.52roadshow.com/activity_index
the images don't fit tight with each other. you can refer the code by viewing the source

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). That's what they are using. Masonry is not the only option though: [Amazing jQuery Plugins to design Pinterest like Dynamic Grid Layout](http://www.wtfdiary.com/2012/08/6-amazing-jquery-plugins-to-design.html)

### Other Resources

http://qnimate.com/creating-cascading-grid-layouts-using-masonry/

http://masonry.desandro.com/

[Is it possible to create a pinterest-like layout with Bootstrap only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570559/is-it-possible-to-create-a-pinterest-like-layout-with-bootstrap-only)

Answer (score -1):

Most of there is using the `absolute position` to implement this, which is the most compatible way. You just need to calculate the `left` and `top` position of your each pin element.

You can refer to this open source plugin here: 
[bootstrap-waterfall](https://github.com/Mystist/bootstrap-waterfall)