# Bootstrap height of columns to flow better

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the columns to take up the remaining space instead of waiting for the end of column. Is the best approach to use to two divs at col-lg-6 and and set the divs inside at col-lg-12? just want to make sure i am using bootstrap the correct way and get rid of any bad habits early on. it will be easier to show in pictures

**my current view**
[image]

**expected result**
[image]

Comment: Only way to do that is with a jQuery pluging called **Isotope** (or **masonery**). <br />I prefer Isotope > http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/fitcolumns.html

Comment: Seems that you need Masonry grid. I found one article about that [article.](https://www.sitepoint.com/bootstrap-tabs-play-nice-with-masonry/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make bootstrap columns take up the least vertical space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32272964/make-bootstrap-columns-take-up-the-least-vertical-space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6" style="border:1px solid #777777;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid #777777;height:100px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid #777777;height:140px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="border:1px solid #777777;">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid #777777;height:150px;">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12" style="border:1px solid #777777;height:100px;">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```