# Bootstrap and it's fluidity

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

I don't know the proper term exactly so I apologize if it's wrong but can bootstrap be fluid? 
What I mean is can I have a total of let's say 6 columns set up to be 4 columns wide each, all of different height. Once the first row is full and it moves down they need to stack despite them all having different heights.
I've played around in bootply trying to accomplish this and I can't. 
Notice how on [Code My UI](http://codemyui.com/) they are all different heights but still stack under each other no matter the height? I'm having a problem accomplishing this.

The following is basic testing with bootstrap:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background:red;">asdasdadsadasdadadasd</div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background:blue;">sadasdad
            <br>sdadasdfasd
            <br>sddasdaddf</div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background:green;">dsgfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf</div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background:red;">asdasdadsadasdadadasd</div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background:blue;">sadasdad
            <br>sdaddf</div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background:green;">dsgfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which produces:
http://www.bootply.com/barrzbteUg

Can a setup such as the one on Code My UI be produced with bootstrap?

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is ["responsive"](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html)?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570559/is-it-possible-to-create-a-pinterest-like-layout-with-bootstrap-only

Answer (score 0):

As said in comment, take a look at 
[cssdeck.com/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout](http://cssdeck.com/labs/css-only-pinterest-style-columns-layout) and [bragthemes.com/demo/pinstrap](http://bragthemes.com/demo/pinstrap/)

or at the SO related post [Is it possible to create a pinterest-like layout with Bootstrap only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570559/is-it-possible-to-create-a-pinterest-like-layout-with-bootstrap-only)